# SharePoint Online SPUtility GetValue empty for People Picker

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-picker, sputility

I am trying to retreive the value of a people picker using SPUtility v0.14.2 in SharePoint Online though it always returns an empty string.

My script is as follows, do I need to retrieve the value using a different method?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var facilitator = SPUtility.GetSPField("Facilitator");
    $(facilitator.Controls).focusout(function() {
        var f = facilitator.GetValue();
        console.log(f);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot directly pick values from People picker fields.
Reason being a people picker field is nothing but a lookup to
a list where SharePoint stores various users.
Some of the values associated with a people picker field are:

--> **Id**

--> **Display Text**

Still it can be done in the following way (Workaround):

Just paste the following code inside **PreSaveAction()**

```
    function PreSaveAction() 
   {
        //alert('PreSaveAction');       
        // Get People Picker Values

        function getEditorPeoplePickerValues(fieldName) 
        {   // Field Title
            var editorNames = "";
            var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");

            var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');

            var ppobject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
            editorsInfo = ppobject.GetAllUserInfo();
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < editorsInfo.length; ++i) {
                editorNames += editorsInfo[i].DisplayText ;
            }
            return editorNames;
        }

        var UserName =   getEditorPeoplePickerValues("You fields name");   

   }
```

Just enter you people picker field's name in the double quotes.

Note: I assume you have already added reference for SPUtility and
Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using only `SPUtility.js` without workaround.

Use

> **`SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('Field_x0020_Internal_x0020_Name').GetValue()[0].EntityData.Email`**

for getting the Email Id

> **`SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('Field_x0020_Internal_x0020_Name').GetValue()[0].DisplayText`**

for getting the Display Text

I am assuming it is a single user people picker. if it is Multi user people picker, just iterate on `GetValue()[]` array and fetch all data you need

Comment: you have to wait for the people picker to resolve before getting the value ..